# Remove duplicates if you have only one column with value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is too easy, if you have `Id` column and `Value` column which has duplicate rows. But in the interview i had been asked how to remove it, if you have only `Value` column. For example:

table_a input:

```
Value
A
A
B
A
C
D
D
E
F
F
E
```

table_a output:

```
Value
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Question: You have table with only one column `Value` and you have to `delete` all rows, which have duplicates (as in result upper).

Comment: IT TO SIMPLE USE DISTINCT IN SELECT QUERY......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are allowed to use CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by Value order by Value) as row_num,
        Value
    from Table1
)
delete from cte where row_num > 1
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6ce6/4)

as t-clausen.dk suggested in comments, you don't even need value inside the CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by Value order by Value) as row_num
    from Table1
)
delete from cte where row_num > 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, gow about using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.

and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
>   set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT [Value],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Value] ORDER BY [Value]) RowID
        FROM    MyTable
    )
DELETE 
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct value
from your_table
```

(not relevant anymore as the question has been updated by the user, see Roman Pekar's answer)

Comment: downvoting this is a bit harsh, considering it actually does what the question ask for +1 to compensate

Comment: we need to delete rows from table, not select